# Can't run java tutorial of vaadin - missing class

Tags: java, maven, vaadin

I tried to get into Vaadin by going through the [tutorial](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/tutorial.html).

I did everything described there but I can't even run it without having a build failure. I created a new Maven Project and selected Vaadin as the Archetype. After that, I made a Maven install on my project that was completed successfully. From there on, I followed the tutorial and configured the debug settings and run the program in debug mode but unfortunately I got the following error and I don't know what went wrong(Figure 5-7 in the tutorial).

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.9.v20160517:run (default-cli) on project app: Execution default-cli of goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.9.v20160517:run failed: A required class was missing while executing org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.9.v20160517:run: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.9.v20160517
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/9.3.9.v20160517/jetty-maven-plugin-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/2.1.1/sisu-inject-bean-2.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.9.4/sisu-guice-2.9.4-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.6/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.11/aether-util-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-api/3.4/maven-plugin-tools-api-3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.3.9.v20160517/jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-webapp/9.3.9.v20160517/jetty-webapp-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-xml/9.3.9.v20160517/jetty-xml-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.3.9.v20160517/jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-quickstart/9.3.9.v20160517/jetty-quickstart-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jaas/9.3.9.v20160517/jetty-jaas-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.3.9.v20160517/jetty-security-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-plus/9.3.9.v20160517/jetty-plus-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jndi/9.3.9.v20160517/jetty-jndi-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.3.9.v20160517/jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.3.9.v20160517/jetty-http-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.3.9.v20160517/jetty-io-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jmx/9.3.9.v20160517/jetty-jmx-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-annotations/9.3.9.v20160517/jetty-annotations-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.1/asm-5.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.0.1/asm-commons-5.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.0.1/asm-tree-5.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/javax-websocket-server-impl/9.3.9.v20160517/javax-websocket-server-impl-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/javax-websocket-client-impl/9.3.9.v20160517/javax-websocket-client-impl-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/javax/websocket/javax.websocket-api/1.0/javax.websocket-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-server/9.3.9.v20160517/websocket-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-common/9.3.9.v20160517/websocket-common-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-api/9.3.9.v20160517/websocket-api-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-client/9.3.9.v20160517/websocket-client-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-servlet/9.3.9.v20160517/websocket-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/apache-jsp/9.3.9.v20160517/apache-jsp-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/toolchain/jetty-schemas/3.1/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jasper/apache-jsp/8.0.33/apache-jsp-8.0.33.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jasper/apache-el/8.0.33/apache-el-8.0.33.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.4.2/ecj-4.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/apache-jstl/9.3.9.v20160517/apache-jstl-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs  /taglibs-standard-spec/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>my.vaadin</groupId>
<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>app</name>

<prerequisites>
    <maven>3</maven>
</prerequisites>

<properties>
    <vaadin.version>8.0.0</vaadin.version>
    <vaadin.plugin.version>8.0.0</vaadin.plugin.version>
    <jetty.plugin.version>9.3.9.v20160517</jetty.plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <!-- If there are no local customisations, this can also be "fetch" or "cdn" -->
    <vaadin.widgetset.mode>local</vaadin.widgetset.mode>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <!-- Exclude an unnecessary file generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-theme</goal>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
                        <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <!-- Clean up also any pre-compiled themes -->
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/styles.css</include>
                            <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by
            running jetty:run on the command line. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- Vaadin pre-release repositories -->
        <id>vaadin-prerelease</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the same [error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19318884/9088543)

Check your version of java and maven and make sure they are compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure 
For the Maven compilation to work you need a JDK(not JRE,by default it may point to JRE) to be configured in your Eclipse in

> Window ▸ Preferences ▸ Java ▸ Installed JREs ▸ Add…​.

This step is necessary at least on Windows, if you are using a fresh installation of Eclipse or for some other reason haven’t configured a JDK to your Eclipse. The JDK by default installs to \Program Files\Java on Windows. You can make JDK the default JRE for your Eclipse.

Comment: JDK is already configured in Eclipse since I worked on my JavaFX project earlier.

Comment: Can you please paste you pom.xml content.May be something wrong with plugin/Dependency config?